# Piping grep causes error $'\302\240grep': command not found on linux

Tags: linux, bash, grep, pipe

Sometimes when piping some input to `grep`, I see this error come up:

```
$ cat something.txt | grep "some text"
-bash: $'\302\240grep': command not found
```

When I re-type the command, it works as expected. What could be the cause?

I'm using Finnish keyboard layout.

Comment: BTW you don't need to use `cat` for this -- just use `grep "some text" something.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key-combination for pipe symbol in Finnish layout is <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + the key between <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>. The problem was that I didn't release <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> before pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> after the pipe character, and that caused a non breaking space to be inserted instead of normal space.

Comment: It's NO-BREAK SPACE (to use the Unicode name) and it isn't really that weird.  Finnish isn't the only multilingual keyboard layout where multiple characters are typeable with the spacebar.  It's also the case for the German T2 layout, for example.